# Are Duplicate Unit Tests OK?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have the following class

```
public interface IAuthProvider
{
    string GenerateKey();
}

public class AuthProvider : IAuthProvider
{
    public string GenerateKey()
    {
        using (var rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            var data = new byte[16];
            rng.GetBytes(data);
            return BitConverter.ToString(data).Replace("-","");
        }
    }
}
```

I also have the follow unit tests to go with it

```
[TestClass]
public class AuthProviderTests
{
    private AuthProvider _provider;
    private string _key;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        _provider = new AuthProvider();
        _key = _provider.GenerateKey();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void GenerateKey_key_length_is_32_characters()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(32, _key.Length);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void GenerateKey_key_is_valid_uppercase_hexidecimal_string()
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(_key.All(c =>
            (c >= '0' && c <= '9') || 
            (c >= 'A' && c <= 'F')
        ));
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void GenerateKey_keys_are_random()
    {
        var keys = new List<string>
            {
                _provider.GenerateKey(),
                _provider.GenerateKey(),
                _provider.GenerateKey(),
                _provider.GenerateKey(),
                _provider.GenerateKey()
            };

        var distinctCount = keys.Distinct().Count();

        Assert.AreEqual(5, distinctCount);
    }
}
```

Everything works great. However I need to create a method (and tests to go with it) called GenerateSecret. This method will do exactly the same as GenerateKey().

Now I am thinking I should create a method called GenerateRandomHexString(int bytes) and copy the code from GenerateKey into it. Then for GenerateKey and GenerateSecret I should use the follow code:

```
public interface IAuthProvider
{
    string GenerateKey();
    string GenerateSecret();
    string GenerateRandomHexString(int bytes);
}

public class AuthProvider : IAuthProvider
{
    public string GenerateKey()
    {
        return GenerateRandomHexString(16);
    }

    public string GenerateSecret()
    {
        return GenerateRandomHexString(16);
    }

    public string GenerateRandomHexString(int bytes)
    {
        using (var rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            var data = new byte[bytes];
            rng.GetBytes(data);
            return BitConverter.ToString(data).Replace("-","");
        }
    }
}
```

Now for the tests, should I just write the tests for the GenerateRandomHexString method, or should I write tests also for the GenerateSecret and GenerateKey (which will be pretty much identical tests)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bad idea to create many interface methods to do the same thing.  I also don't put overloads on interfaces.  The problem this creates is that methods that have the same semantic meaning can have wildly divergent implementations.  They might not in the simplest cases, but simple cases often become complex ones eventually.

I **love** extension methods for this problem.

```
public interface IAuthProvider
{
    string GenerateKey();
}

public static class IAuthProviderExtensions
{
    public static string GenerateSecret(this IAuthProvider provider)
    {
         return provider.GenerateKey();
    }
}
```

Test:

```
[Test]
public void GenerateSecretIsAliasForGenerateKey()
{
    var mockProvider = new Mock<IAuthProvider>();
    var key = GenerateARandomStringSomehow();
    mockProvider.Setup(p=>p.GenerateKey()).Returns(key);
    Assert.That(mockProvider.Object.GenerateSecret(), Is.EqualTo(key));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why do need two methods that do the same thing?

Regardless, you should write separate tests.

- generally unit tests should cover the public interface and not non-public members and your GenerateHexString probably shouldn't be public if it is only to be used by the other methods
- your implementations are the same now, but they may diverge in the future. Without distinct test cases you may miss breaking changes introduced by someone changing one of those implementations
- ultimately your tests shouldn't know or care about the internal implementation details of your code

One thing that might help in nUnit would be the TestCaseSource attribute. It would allow you to define the same test cases for both methods saving some duplication in your code.

Comment: If I was to use one function for both GenerateKey and GenerateSecret. What would I call such a function? GenerateKeyOrSecret?

Comment: Yet another question. If you look at GenerateKey_keys_are_random, does that break the rule of unit tests having to be Deterministic. Since it is possible for more than one key to be the same, just very improbable.